# Send Image to Firebase Storage using URL Google Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-places-api, firebase-storage

I use Google Place API to get place's details (name, address, location, image).
when I send local image to firebase storage it works fine, but when I tried to send image token from Google place API by its URL, I get an error, so there's any way to send it directly without download it to local then send it to firebase storage.

```
Uri filePath = Uri.parse(UrlImageFromGoogle);

StorageReference ref = storageReference.child(UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"/images/");
  ref.putFile(filePath)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) { //call Network}
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
```

Error :

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?key=AIzaSyCPuCP0IcA00y0PtXDVyHHa_CicxR2Ydys&photoreference=CmRaAAAAX7WT3q2MtgOxHNcWaPDIr7GaffmfvbeQpPL0k3MwCb_OBlVo2koiOHr4MUfuOjTaoi7zhUNqasi2DSa6jemykZYD5Tzdl_T06P9sH_MaSM-p39LjctUpYAQFLSuOeF_eEhBAEjX0BMKVMgysaZG6GWQaGhRUdWM-wIbfYq0qCvMdoeXo29dsLQ&maxheight=1000&maxwidth=1000
```

Comment: what is the error? post the stack trace of the error

Comment: I edit my question, you can see it now

Comment: hide your key in the url, it can be misused.....

Comment: you need to first download the image to your phone, save it and then send it to firebase storage as you have already done... you can't pass a url as filepath